# how to get both qgraphicsscene and qgraphicsitem drops?

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

I have some items on a qgraphicsscene and I want to be able to drag and drop an item onto another or onto a blank part of the scene. Depending on whether the drop occurs over another item or over a blank part of the scene two different things happen. How to approach this? i have implemented scene and graphics item drag and drop. but this approach not working, by this both scene and item handles drop events, for me only one should handle based on dropping position.
Below is working example.
when i drag rect1 and droppped on rect2, i should get rect2 drop event.
when i drag rect1 and droppped on blank scene, i should get scene drop event.

**graphicsview.h**

```
   class GraphicsView : public QGraphicsView
  {
    public:
      GraphicsView();
   };
```

**graphicsview.cpp**

```
GraphicsView::GraphicsView()
{
 //setAcceptDrops(true);
}
```

**graphicsScene.h**

```
    class GraphicsScene : public QGraphicsScene
    {
     public:
         GraphicsScene();
    protected:
        void dragEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event);
        void dragMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event);
        void dropEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event);
    };
```

**graphicsScene.cpp**

```
GraphicsScene::GraphicsScene()
{

}

void GraphicsScene::dragEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
{
  qDebug() << "Scene::dragEnterEvent";
   event->acceptProposedAction();
}

void GraphicsScene::dragMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
{
   qDebug() << "Scene::dragMoveEvent";
   event->acceptProposedAction();
}

void GraphicsScene::dropEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
{
  qDebug() << "Scene::dropEvent";
  event->acceptProposedAction();
}
```

**graphicsRectItem.h**

```
class GraphicsRectItem : public QGraphicsRectItem
{
  public:
      GraphicsRectItem();

       static QString MimeType() { return QStringLiteral("job/x-job"); }
 protected:
   void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
   void mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
    void dragEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event);
     void dragMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event);
     void dropEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event);
  };
```

**graphicsRectItem.cpp**

```
GraphicsRectItem::GraphicsRectItem()
{
      setAcceptDrops(true);
 }

void GraphicsRectItem::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
   qDebug() << "RectItem::mousePressEvent";
   setCursor(Qt::ClosedHandCursor);

}

 void GraphicsRectItem::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
 {
    qDebug() << "RectItem::mouseMoveEvent";
     if (QLineF(event->screenPos(), event- 
            >buttonDownScreenPos(Qt::LeftButton))
         .length() < QApplication::startDragDistance()) {
        QGraphicsRectItem::mouseMoveEvent(event);
       return;
  }
    qDebug() << "drag before executed";

     QByteArray itemData;
     QString m_jobName = "rect";
      DataStream dataStream(&itemData, QIODevice::WriteOnly);


      dataStream << m_jobName ;

       QMimeData *mimeData = new QMimeData;
       mimeData->setData(GraphicsRectItem::MimeType(), itemData);

      QDrag *drag = new QDrag(event->widget());
     drag->setMimeData(mimeData);
     drag->exec();
      qDebug() << "drag executed";
     setCursor(Qt::OpenHandCursor);


    }

   void GraphicsRectItem::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
  {
        qDebug() << "RectItem::mouseReleaseEvent";
       setCursor(Qt::OpenHandCursor);
  }

  void GraphicsRectItem::dragEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
  {
        qDebug() << "RectItem::dragEnterEvent";
        event->acceptProposedAction();
  }

  void GraphicsRectItem::dragMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
  {
       qDebug() << "RectItem::dragMoveEvent";
         event->acceptProposedAction();
   }

 void GraphicsRectItem::dropEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
 {
      qDebug() << "RectItem::dropEvent";
        event->acceptProposedAction();
  }
```

**Mainwindow.cpp**

```
 MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
 QMainWindow(parent),
 ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
 {
    ui->setupUi(this);
     m_pView = new GraphicsView;
      m_pScene = new GraphicsScene;
      m_pView->setScene(m_pScene);

      GraphicsRectItem *rect1 = new GraphicsRectItem;
      rect1->setRect(10,10,55,55);

      GraphicsRectItem *rect2 = new GraphicsRectItem;
      rect2->setRect(75,10,55,55);

     m_pScene->addItem(rect1);
     m_pScene->addItem(rect2);

     this->setCentralWidget(m_pView);
  }

   MainWindow::~MainWindow()
  {
     delete ui;
  }
```

Comment: I would suggest to let the view handle the drop and filter out those events into the blank parts. Events over existing items would then be forwarded to the scene.

Comment: @Martin Hennings Thank you.can you suggest the example or piece of code filtering out blank part events.

Comment: Please, provide your code.